# Discord бот не показывает команды

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord

Код:

```py
import asyncio

import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import re

TOKEN = 'Тут токен'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=discord.Intents.all(), help_command=None)

def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} подключен к Discord!')

@commands.hybrid_command(name="кик-за-ник", description="Кикает людей с неправильными никами")
@commands.guild_only()

async def kick(ctx):
    safe_roles = [1177625102343491665, 1177625102330892337]  # ID безопасных ролей
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        # Проверяем, что у пользователя нет безопасной роли
        if not any(role.id in safe_roles for role in member.roles):
            # Теперь проверяем ник пользователя
            if not re.match(r'\[.*\]\[.*\].*', member.display_name):
                await member.kick(reason='Некорректный никнейм')
                print(f'{member.display_name} кикнут с сервера: Некорректный никнейм.')
    await ctx.send('Процесс кикания пользователей с неправильными никами завершен.')

@commands.hybrid_command(name="помощь", description="Показывает справку")
@commands.guild_only()

async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.blue())
    embed.set_author(name='Помощь')
    embed.add_field(name='Не знаете что делать?', value='Вам в навигатор: <#1177625103035535382>.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Нужна помощь?', value='Упомяните роль <@1177625102314123346> в чате.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Вы новичок?', value='Для начала установите ник по форме: `[SNN SF][Ваш Ранг]Ваш_Ник`', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Не знаете как поменять ник на сервере?', value='Нажмите на кнопку ниже!', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Владельцы', value='Set_Black, Frady_Freeman, Olya_King', inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text='Создано @ikdan')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@commands.hybrid_command(name="верифицировать", description="Верификация пользователя")
@commands.guild_only()
@app_commands.choices(ранг=[
        app_commands.Choice(name=f"1", value=1),
        app_commands.Choice(name=f"2", value=2),
        app_commands.Choice(name=f"3", value=3),
        app_commands.Choice(name=f"4", value=4),
        app_commands.Choice(name=f"5", value=5),
        app_commands.Choice(name=f"6", value=6),
        app_commands.Choice(name=f"7", value=7),
        app_commands.Choice(name=f"8", value=8),
        app_commands.Choice(name=f"9", value=9)
    ])
@app_commands.describe(
        ник='Ник пользователя в формате Name_Surname'
    )

async def verify(ctx, ранг: app_commands.Choice[int], ник: str):
    verification_channel = bot.get_channel(1177625103681466394)
    user_mention = ctx.author.mention

    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.blue())
    embed.add_field(name='Верификация пользователя', value=f'{user_mention} хочет верифицироваться, запрашиваемый ник: [CNN SF][{ранг}]{ник}!', inline=False)
    verification_message = await verification_channel.send(embed=embed)
    await verification_message.add_reaction('✅')
    await verification_message.add_reaction('❌')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['✅', '❌']

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=3600.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send('Время вышло. Верификация не завершена.')
    else:
        if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
            await ctx.author.edit(nick=f'[CNN SF][{ранг}] {ник}')
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=1177625102314123348)
            await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
            await verification_channel.send(f'Сотрудник {user.mention} верифицировал {ctx.author.mention} с ником [CNN SF][{ранг}]{ник}')
        elif str(reaction.emoji) == '❌':
            await verification_channel.send(f'Сотрудник {user.mention} отклонил верификацию {ctx.author.mention} с ником [CNN SF][{ранг}]{ник}')

@commands.hybrid_command(name="навигатор", description="Показывает навигатор по каналам")
@commands.guild_only()

async def navigator(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.blue())
    embed.add_field(name='<#1136898381046882354>', value='Упрощает сотрудникам нашей организации перемещения по разделам текстового чата.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='<#1136898482884591647>', value='Канал для стажеров, там можно найти тест на ПРО.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='<#1136898669002641469>', value='Канал с информацией и суммами о премиях.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='<#1136898737675960441>', value='Канал для отчетов на получение премии.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='<#1159091362977808434>', value='Канал для конкурсов сотрудникам.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='<#1136899268146372648>', value='Тэги для объявлений в СМИ.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='<#1136899337436266516>', value='Информация для сотрудников редакции.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='<#1136899456034410559>', value='Информация для сотрудников ОПЭ.', inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(TOKEN, reconnect=True)
```

Если я напишу /помощь, то в консоли появится ошибка: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "помощь" is not found`